# Listview for 2 Fields on firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

want to make a Listview for 2 Fields on Firebase called `customer` and I have a `problem`. This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.eranp.clientpage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                        //ההודעה כאשר אתה יוצא מהאפליקציה
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Please ComeBack!";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }


    private EditText fName_ET;
    private EditText lName_ET;
    private EditText phoneNum_ET;
    private EditText eMail_ET;
    private EditText deviceModel_ET;
    private EditText nameDevice_ET;
    private Button nextPage, btnViewAll;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnViewAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_viewAllM);
       fName_ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fName_ET);
       lName_ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lName_ET);
       phoneNum_ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_ET);
       eMail_ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mail_ET);
       nameDevice_ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_device);
       deviceModel_ET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.model_device);
       nextPage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn);

        nextPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                String fName =  fName_ET.getText().toString().trim();
                String lName =  lName_ET.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = eMail_ET.getText().toString().trim();
                String phone = phoneNum_ET.getText().toString().trim();
                String nameDevice = nameDevice_ET.getText().toString().trim();
                String modelDevice =deviceModel_ET.getText().toString().trim();
                intent.putExtra("modelDevice",modelDevice);
                intent.putExtra("fName", fName);
                intent.putExtra("lName", lName);
                intent.putExtra("phone", phone);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                intent.putExtra("nameDevice", nameDevice);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","Loading..Wait.." , true);
                dialog.show();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //your code here
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 5000);  // 3000 milliseconds
                Intent intentl = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomersPage.class);
                startActivity(intentl);


            }
        });


    }

}
```

Main2Activity

```
package com.example.eranp.clientpage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {


    private EditText pro_device_det;
    private Button saveDataBase, btnViewAll ;
    private DatabaseReference databaseCustomer, databaseDevice, databaseProblem;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        databaseCustomer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customer");
        databaseDevice = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("device");
        databaseProblem = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("problem");
        saveDataBase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        btnViewAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_viewAll);


        pro_device_det = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pro_device_det);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fName");
        final String lName = intent.getStringExtra("lName");
        final String phone = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
        final String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        final String modelDevice = intent.getStringExtra("modelDevice");
        final String nameDevice = intent.getStringExtra("nameDevice");

        saveDataBase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String proDeviceDet = pro_device_det.getText().toString().trim();
                String shortProDeviceDet = string3Words(proDeviceDet);
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
                String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(proDeviceDet)) {
                    String id = databaseCustomer.push().getKey();
                    Customer customer = new Customer(id, fName, lName, email, phone);
                    databaseCustomer.child(id).setValue(customer);
                    Device device = new Device(id, nameDevice, modelDevice);
                    databaseDevice.child(id).setValue(device);
                    Problem problem = new Problem(id, date, proDeviceDet, 0, shortProDeviceDet);
                    databaseProblem.child(id).setValue(problem);

                      Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this , "Customer added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Please write on an empty cell", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                Intent intentl = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, CustomersPage.class);
                startActivity(intentl);


            }
        });


    }

    private String string3Words(String s) {
        String[] splitted = s.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            sb.append(splitted[i] + " ");
            if (i == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        String newS = sb.toString();
        return newS;
    }
}
```

> Adding data working successfully

But how can I do `ListView`  to get:
TextView with full name (fName, lName)
and after getting the `proDevDetShort` on the TextView and all of this do at new activity on ListView.

Thank you for helping!